# How can I do getComputedStyle in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, styles, getcomputedstyle

I have an `div` and I don't set any style to it, then I put some content into it, so it height could grows

Now I want to get its height in IE8 or IE7, which have not `getComputedStyle` method

If I use `currentStyle` property, the return value is `auto`, not the number;

How can I get the height in IE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `getComputedStyle`, use [clientHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.clientHeight) or [offsetHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements) depending on wether you want borders included in the total.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements